# How to completely remove locale from Manjaro Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, manjaro, locale, language

I recently had the (in hindsight stupid) ideas to enable a second locale on my computer in addition to en_CA. This second locale was zh_CN. To make sure it worked (and to "check it out"), I turned it on. It worked successfully so I turned it back to English. On the next boot, I noticed that some apps (not all) were still in Chinese. In response to this, I removed zh_CN completely from the active locales list in the KDE Settings Manager. This did **not** fix the issue.

In addition, all coreutils commands were in Chinese, which made doing many things *very difficult*.

I did lots of research and tried many things:

`export LC_ALL=C` : This fixed the issue on the command line BUT UTF-8 wouldn't work

Setting every locale to en_CA.UTF-8 : Did not work

Regenerating only English locales: Did not work

`export LANGUAGE=en_CA.UTF-8` : Did work for the CLI but some things still were in Chinese

`localepurge` everything but English : Did work for most things, but it still isn't completely removed.

Despite all of my efforts, I still run into the occasional blocks of Chinese, namely in the Manjaro Package Manager:

[image: Some things in Chinese]

[image: Even more chinese]
[image: I've had quite enough]

The output of my locale command is

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_CA.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_CA.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_CA.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_CA.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_CA.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_CA.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_CA.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_CA.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_CA.UTF-8
```

It all looks correct. Can someone help me completely rid my system of this locale?

Thanks in advance. (Also apologies in advance if I am doing something stupid or missing something obvious)

**My OS is Manjaro Linux KDE Edition 23.0.3 (Plasma 5.27.8)**

Comment: Does `~/.config/plasma-localerc` exist on your system? What does it contain?

Comment: It does, it contains ```[Formats]
LANG=en_US.UTF-8

[Translations]
LANGUAGE=en_US:zh_CN
```

Comment: I have removed the zh_CN part and I will see if it works. Thank you so much, I would never think to look there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments, you already checked and fixed `~/.config/plasma-localerc`.

Check also the system default locale settings, using the `localectl` command. Those system defaults might be the only locale settings any services invoked via the system D-Bus might get, and the package manager's privileged component might well be such a service.